# JPA design for saving a complex game state

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, database-design

Suppose I have a game with a map and units on it and I want to provide a save option on the server using JPA 2.2. Here are simplified classes to represent it:

```
@Entity
class GameState {

    @Id
    long gameId;

    Map<Point, Tile> map;

    Map<Long, Unit> units; // maps from the id to the unit
    Map<Long, Soldier> soldiers; // maps from the id to the soldier
}
```

```
@Entity
class Tile {

    @Id
    long entityId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tile")
    Unit unit; // null if no unit on this tile
}
```

```
@Entity
class Unit {

    @Id
    long entityId;
    
    @OneToOne
    Tile tile; // null if the unit is not on a tile

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Soldier> soldiers;
}
```

```
@Entity
class Soldier {

    @id
    long entityId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Unit unit;        

    int health;
}
```

```
final class Point {

    final int x, y;
}
```

so each tile can have a unit on it, and each unit has some soldiers in it.

I have several issues:

1. Since there can be many games, the `entityId` of `Unit` `Soldier` and `Tile` is not unique. There can be a soldier with id of 1 in each game. I'm not sure if i can/should use `@Embedded` or if I can use a complex id made of the entity id and the game id.
2. What is the appropriate annotations for `Point`? It's immutable.
3. What is the appropriate annotations for the maps? I thought something like

   ```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "unit_mapping", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "unit_id", referencedColumnName = "entityId")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "unit_id", referencedColumnName = "entityId")})
    @MapKey(name = "id")
   ```

This is my attempt, but if there is a better approach I'd like to know. Previously I just serialized the whole state as a blob, but I want to be able to query finer details of the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the appropriate annotations for the maps?

The simplest would be to use a `@JoinColumn` instead of a `@JoinTable` (and I believe it is the only feasible mapping if you're planning on making the `Game` id part of the primary key for `Unit`s or `Soldier`s):

```
@OneToMany(cascadeType = ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "game_id")
@MapKey(name = "entityId")
private Map<Long, Unit> units;
```

The above mapping will create a `game_id` column inside the `UNIT` table. If you insist on using intermediary join tables instead, then the correct mapping would be sth like:

```
@OneToMany(cascadeType = ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "unit_mapping", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id")
)
@MapKey(name = "entityId")
private Map<Long, Unit> units;
```

> What is the appropriate annotations for Point? It's immutable.

Since `Point` does not have an identity, I'd suggest you make it an `@Embeddable`

> how do i make the complex ID using the game id with the entity id?

First of all, If I were you, I'd really challenge myself to figure out how many `Soldier`s and `Unit`s there can be. A `long` is a really huuuuuge number, and as you're about to see, the mapping gets pretty complicated using the composite key.

However, if you decide you'll need a composite key after all, you'll need to adjust the mapping, changing the unidirectional `@OneToMany` to a bidirectional one, with a shared key. The result will look sth like this:

```
public class UnitKey implements Serializable {

    private long entityId;
    private long gameId;

    //getters, setters, equals, hashCode
}

@Entity
@IdClass(UnitKey.class) // in principle, you could use an EmbeddedId instead, but IdClass is a little more convenient with PKs made partly of FKs IMHO
public class Unit {

    @Id
    private long entityId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id")
    @MapsId("gameId")
    private Game game;
}

@Entity
public class Game {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game", cascadeType = ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "entityId")
    private Map<Long, Unit> units;

}
```

Note that `Unit` is not the *owning side* of the association. This means that any changes to the association have to be done by adjusting the `Unit.game` property. In particular, to add a new `Unit`, to a `Game`, it is not enough to add a `Unit` to the `Game.units` map - you also need to manually set the `Unit.game` property to point to the `Game` in question.

Note that I haven't tested the above mapping. Though it should work in principle, I've never tried combining a map on one side with a composite key on the other, so - no guarantees given.

Comment: Why do you need `Game game` in `Unit` and not just the `long gameId`?

Comment: Well, you *could* try mapping it with just the `gameId`, but I'm not 100% sure JPA will handle the order of insertion correctly when you persist the `Game` *and* `Unit`s at the same time. You would have to check. Bear in mind that you will then have the `GAME_ID` column mapped twice, once as a `@JoinColumn`, and the other time as the `@Id`. One of those mappings will have to be marked `insertable=false, updatable = false`

Comment: If you want to try such a mapping, I'd first try putting `insertable = false, updatable = false` on the `@JoinColumn` and assigning the game id to each `Unit.gameId` manually.